# Class not declared in scope in main

Tags: c++, makefile, scope

"dlist_test.cc:16: error: 'testList' was not declared in this scope.

dlist_test.cc:16: error: 'Dlist' was not declared in this scope."

I have been looking at other threads on circular dependences or namespace but I only have one header file, and I'm not using a namespace for dlist.h or dlist.cc. Where am I not declaring this correctly? Is it a Makefile problem? Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

dlist.h:

```
#ifndef DLIST_H
#define DLIST_H

struct ListNode 
{
  /* define your list node type */
  int val;
  ListNode* next;
  ListNode* prev;
};

class DList
{
  public:
  DList();
  /* implement copy constructor, assignment, destructor if needed */
  void add_to_front(int value);
  void add_to_back(int value);
  int first();
  int last();
  void remove(ListNode* node);
  ListNode* previous(ListNode* node);
  ListNode* next(ListNode* node);
  ListNode* search_value(int value);

  private:
  /* declare your data */
  ListNode* head;
  ListNode* tail;
};

#endif
```

dlist.cc

```
#include "dlist.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Dlist{
   public:

      Dlist(){
               head = NULL;
               tail = NULL;
      }

      void add_to_front(int value){ 
         struct ListNode* newhead = (struct ListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode)); 
         newhead->val  = value; 
         newhead->prev = NULL; 
         newhead->next = head;     
         if(head !=  NULL) 
            head->prev = newhead ;     
         head = newhead; 
      }   

      void add_to_back(int value){
         if (tail == NULL){
            struct ListNode* firstValue = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            firstValue->val = value;
            firstValue->prev = NULL;
            firstValue->next = NULL;
            tail = firstValue;
         }else{
            struct ListNode* newtail = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            newtail->val = value;
            newtail->next = NULL;
            newtail->prev = tail;

            tail->next = newtail;

            tail = newtail;
         }
      }

      int first(){
         return head->val;
      }

      int last(){
         return tail->val;
      }

      void remove(ListNode* node){
         if (head == NULL || node == NULL){
            return;
         }

         if(head == node){
            head = node->next;
         }

         if (node->next != NULL){
            node->next->prev = node->prev;
         }
         if (node->prev != NULL){
            node->prev->next = node->next;
         }
         free(node);
      }

      ListNode* previous(ListNode* node){
         if(node->prev != NULL){
            return node->prev;
         }
      }

      ListNode* next(ListNode* node){
         if(node->next != NULL){
            return node->next;
         }
      }

      ListNode* search_value(int value){
         while(head->next != NULL){
            if(head->next->val == value){
               return head;
            }else{
               head = head->next;
            }
         }
      }
   private:
      ListNode* head;
      ListNode* tail;

   };
```

dlist_test.cc

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "dlist.h"
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int N = -1;
  if (argc == 2) {
    N = atoi (argv[1]);
    assert (N > 0);
  } 
  testList = Dlist();
  int i = 0;
  while(i<N){
    testList.add_to_back(i+1);
    i++;
  }
  int randn = rand() % N + 1;// randn in the range 1 to N
  //
  time_t start, end;
  time(&start); 
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
  struct ListNode* loc = testList.search_value(randn);
  testList.remove(loc);
  time(&end); 
  double time_taken = double(end - start); 
    cout << "Time taken by program is : " << fixed 
         << time_taken << setprecision(5); 
    cout << " sec " << endl; 
  //
  testList.add_to_front(N);


  return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
default:
    @echo "=================================================="
    @echo "To build your sorting code, use:"
    @echo "make dlist_test or  make queue_test"
    @echo "=================================================="

# Queue driver
queue_test: queue.o


# Doubly linked list driver
dlist_test: dlist.o dlist_test.o
    g++ -o dlist_test dlist.o dlist_test.o

dlist.o: dlist.cc dlist.h
    g++ -c dlist.cc

dlist_test.o: dlist_test.cc
    g++ -c dlist_test.cc

clean:
    rm -f core *.o *~ queue_test dlist_test

# eof
```

Comment: Instead  testList = Dlist(); Define it as Dlist testList;

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @user1438832, unfortunately, the same issue occurs still even if i write "Dlist testList".

Comment: This is not the error you are seeing right now, but you also are implementing the class wrong. Instead of implementing the member functions in the `dlist.cc` file, you are re-defining the class, which will cause an error as well. I suggest you have another look at how classes are supposed to be implemented in your instructional material (or get some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)).

Comment: Furthermore, `malloc`/`free` is almost always wrong in C++. In your specific case here it is technically undefined behavior. You must use `new`/`delete` instead or rather, you should use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Writing `struct` before a type name in a variable declaration as in `struct ListNode* newhead` is sometimes required in C, but is practically always redundant in C++. Please don't do this, since it can have unintended side effects.

Comment: Then also have a look at [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Given that you are including other standard library headers at the same time with it, it seems that you don't know what it actually does. Also don't include the `<[...].h>` versions of C library headers, but use the `<c[...]>` versions instead.

Comment: Instead of `NULL` you should always use `nullptr` since C++11.

Comment: @walnut, thank you for the pointers. I typically code in C and am learning the ropes of C++. This is all very helpful as I'm not too sure of what I'm doing wrong myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different problems:

1) C++ distinguishes uppercase letters from lowercase ones. You declared the class as `DList` so you need write this name exactly this way. `Dlist` (with lower case "L") is considered an entirely different name.

2) You've never created variable `testList` so C++ is right to tell that it doesn't exist. It happens to the best ;)
Just change the line

```
testList = Dlist();
```

to

```
Dlist testList = Dlist();
```

or

```
Dlist testList;
```

The both variants are equivalent. C++ will use a constructor without parameters by default.

Comment: I was figuring that it was something I couldn't put my finger on. I've been staring at this for two hours already and I did not notice the miscapitalization at all. After implementing your suggestions, the scope issue has been solved. However, there are new issues that come up such as "dlist_test,cc:(.text+0x5a: undefined reference to 'DList::DList()'" and 'Dlist::add_to_back(int)', etc. Am i calling the method functions incorrectly?

Comment: @NicholasChiu This looks like a linker error. Here is some information about this type of error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/3052438
If this doesn't solve the problem, please ask another question.

Comment: @NicholasChiu Actually, I can see the problem. walnut has pointed it in a comment earlier. You syntax in `dist.cc` looks like another class declaration. You need to define it instead.